# SQL Server 2008: How to insert one image per each entry in a Table?

Tags: sql-server, image, blob

In my SQL Server Management Studio 2008 project I have created a table called

```
Catalog (
    catalogId NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    catalogName VARCHAR(20), 
    CatalogImage VARBINARY(MAX)
    )
```

with 3 entries:

```
catalogId | catalogName | catalogImage
    1     |     jon     |     NULL
    2     |     jim     |     NULL
    3     |     joe     |     NULL
```

I wish to add one image per each entry in my table.
The following query for inserting an image, for example for jon:

```
INSERT INTO Catalog (catalogImage)
SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET( Bulk 'C:\images\jon.bmp', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
WHERE catalogId=1
```

produces the error message "*Invalid column name 'catalogId'.*"

What is the correct query?

Thank you very much in advance,
Greg

Answer (score 6):

Since you already have the entries use UPDATE instead of INSERT

```
UPDATE Catalog SET catalogImage = 
(SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET( Bulk 'C:\images\jon.bmp', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB)
WHERE catalogId=1
```

(untested as well)

Comment: Thank you very much user495812 and sunn0! Both of you are correct!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to update the rows instead of inserting new ones. Try (untested):

```
UPDATE Catalog set catalogImage = (SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET( Bulk 'C:\images\jon.bmp', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB) WHERE catalogId = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much user495812 and sunn0! Both of you are correct!